# Thread safe Ring Buffer

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, buffer

I have this Ring Buffer of maximum size 10. There are two thread sharing its object. One thread pushes new element, other pops it.When buffer is empty or full, a thread should **wait** instead of replacing an element.
Problem is some random characters are skipped.

```
public class CircularBuffer {
private byte[][] data = new byte[10][1024];
private int[] numRead = new int[10];
private int rp,wp,num;   //read pointer,write pointer,no of data
public boolean isReadComplete;
public boolean isComplete;
private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
public CircularBuffer()
{
    rp=0;
    num=0;
    wp=0;
    isReadComplete=false;;
    isComplete=false;
}
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    if(num==0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
public  void push(byte d[],int n)
{
    while(num==10){
        System.out.println("read waiting");
    }
    data[rp]=d;
    numRead[rp]=n;

    try{
        lock.lock();
        num++;
    }
    finally
    {
        lock.unlock();
    }
    if(rp==9)
        rp=0;
    else
        rp++;
}
public  boolean pop(Byt b)
{
    while(num==0){
        if(isReadComplete)
        {
            isComplete=true;
            System.out.println("Done writing");
            return true;

        }
        System.out.println("write waiting");

    }
    b.b=data[wp];
    b.numRead=numRead[wp];
    try{
        lock.lock();
        num--;
    }
    finally
    {
        lock.unlock();
    }
    if(wp==9)
        wp=0;
    else
        wp++;

     return false;
}
```

}

Comment: There's a lock-free ring buffer [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12691/o1-lock-free-container).

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
if(wp==9)
    wp=0;
else
    wp++;
```

Is not good in a multithreaded environment. It is quite possible for one thread to do the `if(wp==9)` and find it `false` and then add `1` to it, meanwhile another thread has just found the value at `8` and incremented it to `9`. The first thread then does it's `wp++` and it now holds `10`.

You should use something like:

```
wp = (wp+1)%10;
```

You also do that elsewhere.

That may not be **the** problem as it would crash with an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` but it is certainly **a** problem with the code.

Comment: `wp` is used by `Read` thread only. So I don't think it will be a problem.